# Minimum in a non-linear system

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, control-theory, vector-fields

I have the linear system:

$$\begin{cases}\dot{x}=y\\
\dot{y}=-ay+x-x^3\end{cases}$$

where $a\geq 0$.

I want to prove that this dynamical system has two minimum.

I found the 3 equilibrium points $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$.

I calculated the jacobian and i don't know how to proceed.
I have read something about minimum points when the Jacobian is positive definitive but these matrices are not.

Comment: What do you mean by "a system has a minimum"?

Comment: the question is :why this is a system that moves in symmetrical dynamic with two minimum?

Comment: The symmetry is clear from the fact that your vector field is symmetric w.r.t. the origin, that is $F(x,y)=-F(-x,-y)$. I guess that the "two minima" refers to the fact that the stationary solutions (equilibrium points) $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ are stable.To check stability you just compute the eigenvalues of the linearized problem, which must be negative or complex with non-positive real part.

Comment: this means that every time i have stable equilibrium points i am gonna have minimum?

Comment: I think a minimum you are referring to can be interpreted as all points you can converge to if you start sufficiently close to them. But I can imagine that this can be confusing, since normally a minimum is defined with respect to some cost function.
PS: it can also help if you [visualize it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?x=-1526&y=-71&i=streamplot%5B%7By,-y%2Bx-x%5E3%7D,%7Bx,-3,3%7D,%7By,-3,3%7D%5D).

Answer (score 2):

As @GReyes proposed you need to linearize the system at the equilibrium points $\boldsymbol{x}_\text{eq}=[x_\text{eq},y_\text{eq}]^T$, which are $[0,0]^T$ and $[\pm 1,0]^T$.

If we write the system in vector form, by using $\boldsymbol{x}=[x,y]^T$ and $\boldsymbol{f}=[f_1(\boldsymbol{x}),f_2(\boldsymbol{x})]^T$
$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x})$$
we can simply get the linarized system matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ by

$$\boldsymbol{A} = \left.\dfrac{\partial \boldsymbol{f}}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}\right|_{\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{x}_\text{eq}}$$

Written out for our problem this is given by

$$\boldsymbol{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}& \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\\
\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}& \dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}_{\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{x}_\text{eq}}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1-3x^2_\text{eq} & -a\end{bmatrix}.$$

The eigenvalues of this system are given by the characteristic polynomial

$$\chi(s)=s^2+as+(3x^2_\text{eq}-1).$$

If $a>0$ and $3x^2_\text{eq}-1>0$ are fulfilled the system is Hurwitz, hence the equilibrium point is asymptotically stable. You can quickly check these properties for the given equilibrium points. Only the origin is unstable but all other equilibrium points are asymptotically stable in a neighborhood of the equilibrium points.

As @Kwin van der Veen proposed. The phase diagram looks like a landscape with hills (unstable equilibrium points) and valleys (asymptotically stable equilibrium points). If you imagine a ball starting somewhere (initial conditions) in this landscape the ball will converge to one of the asymptotically stable equilibrium points (we exclude the trivial origin as a starting point), by following the dynamics of the system (given by the arrows in the phase diagram provided by @Kwin van der Veen).

The hard part is actually the case $a=0$. For the equilibrium point $[0,0]^T$ you can still use the linearization theorem by Lyapunov. But for the other equilibrium points, you will need to find a Lyapunov function to show stability.

**EDIT**: I just couldn't resist :D. In order to show the stability of the system at the equilibrium points $[0,\pm 1]^T$ we divide both equations to obtain

$$dy/dx = \dfrac{x-x^3}{y} \implies 1/2y^2-1/2x^2+1/4x^4-c=0.$$

Now, we define $\Phi(x,y)=  1/2y^2-1/2x^2+1/4x^4$ and evaluate this function at the equilibrium points $x_\text{eq}=\pm 1$ to get $\Phi_\text{eq}=-1/4$. Now, we construct a Lyapunov function candidate

$$V(x,y)=\Phi(x,y)-\Phi_\text{eq}=1/2y^2-1/2x^2+1/4x^4+1/4$$
$$=1/4\left[(1-x^2)^2+2y^2\right].$$

You can see that the function $V$ is positive definite in the vicinity of the equilibrium points $[\pm 1,0]^T$ and $V=0$ for the equilibrium points.
It is clear that $\dot{V}=0$. Because $\Phi(x,y)$ and $\Phi_\text{eq}$ are constants. You can also derive this by differentiating $V$ and using the differential equations for $a=0$. Hence, we can conclude that the equilibrium points are stable.

Comment: What is going if I have a system that has no Equilibrium points.For example $\dot{x}$=y and $\dot{y}=-ay-sinx+T, where T>1 and a>=0.Is it stable?

Comment: For nonlinear systems, we do not say if the system is stable or not. For nonlinear systems, we only look at special solutions (equilibrium points, limit cycles or specific solutions) and try to determine if they are stable. We cannot talk about the stability of equilibrium points in this case. The system cannot have limit cycles because that would imply an equilibrium point in the inner region, which we do not have. The last thing that you could check is if there is a stable solution (e.g. if all trajectories escape to infinity in the same fashion). But you will need to find the solution :).